# Real Time Data with WCF

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, wcf

I have a mssql server that holds realtime data for calls in a call center. To limit queries to the server I have created a WCF service to query that DB.

Using either winforms or wpf in C# I would like to show this data in as near realtime as I can.

I am currently binding a GridView to an ObservableCollection and populating the collection with the WCF service.

This works, but it has a 10+ second lag between updates, not matter how fast I request them.

How can I get "live" data from this mssql server using wcf?

Comment: is your problem getting the data into the collection timely, or is it getting the client to be aware of and responsive to the update?

Comment: they are two very separate sets of challenges.  For getting the client to receive the data, you might want to go down the path of SignalR.  For the Data side you'll want to look down the path of either triggers, service broker or CDC to create small data sets to poll from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are using polling (i.e. some sort of timer or loop that constantly queries the database) to get your data.  That way you will struggle to get real-time updates.

Have you investigated getting the data as a stream from the call centre?

Another approach could be to look at something like [Service Broker](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345108(v=sql.90).aspx) to [notify you about new updates](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_service_broker/archive/2008/07/09/real-time-data-integration-with-service-broker-and-other-sql-techniques.aspx).

Comment: This is Cisco UCCE, I have yet to find a way other than SQL to get the data. Yes I am using a DispatcherTimer. Based on a brief glance at those links it would require DB mods, something that I cannot do without rolls of red tape.